# Vertx SockJS server vs sockjs-tornado

Tags: python, tornado, vert.x, sockjs

I've been inspecting two similar solutions for supporting web sockets via sockJS using an independent Python server, and so far I found two solutions.

I need to write a complex, scalable web socket based web application, and I'm afraid it will be hard to scale Tornado, and it seems Vertx is better with horizontal scaling of web sockets.

I also understand that Redis can be used in conjunction with Tornado for scaling a pub/sub system horizontally, and HAproxy for scaling the SockJS requests.

Between Vertx and Tornado, what is the preferred solution for writing a scalable system which supports SockJS?

Comment: Both are ok. Don't see problems with scaling tornado. Vertx may be easier, haven't looked at it.

Answer (score 3):

Vertx has build-in clustering support. I haven't tried it with many nodes, but it seemed to work well with a few. Internally it uses hazelcast to organise the nodes.
Vertx also runs on a JVM, which has already many monitoring/admin tools which might be useful. So Vertx seems to me like the "batteries included" solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Sockjs Tornado + Rabbit MQ + Memcached in order to scale horizontally.
RabbitMQ brocker will play role of messaging bus from physical Server A  to physical Server B. 
All information about servers may be stored in memcache. For instance you need to send message  M from client-socket C1(A) to client-socket C2(B):

- if receiver of A hosted on the same server (by checking memcache), send msg directly using SockJS Router
- otherwise send M via RabbitMQ brocker B1(A) (by using routing logic) to B2(A), where SockJS router B can directly send your message to original receiver C2(B).

Since AMQP protocol of RabbitMQ utilizing Erlang, message passing is very stable and quite good for high-load distributed applications. To support my words, look here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/

Each physical server (with the following power Xenon 4-nodes, MEM 4Gb, HDD- 140 -1000Gb) can handle 3-5 sockjs tornado instances. SockJS implementation also quite good utilizes reverse proxy (HaProxy) via additional params in url.

For distributed testing you can use gemetr, or tsung (based on erlang).

I used this approach in couple of distributed apps.

In addition, don't forget to use Tornado memory as L1 cache.